# Python2: overriding unittest.fail()

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a fairly large test suite and need to change the behavior of unittest.fail()

Specifically, I want to save all app logs somewhere, when a test fails:

```
class SomeTests(unittest.TestCase):    
    [....]
    def fail(self, msg=None):
        self.save_all_logs()
        <<call regular unittest.fail()>>
```

How to correctly implement the **"call regular unittest.fail()"** line?

Also, if unittest.fail() is overridden this way, will this overriden method be called when a test fails by means of, say, unittest.assertTrue() ?

Comment: `super(SomeTests, self).fail(msg)`?

Comment: that seems to work. as for:

`Also, if unittest.fail() is overridden this way, will this overriden method be called when a test fails by means of, say, unittest.assertTrue() ?`

no, this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

for future reference, the code looks like this:

```
def fail(self, msg=None, calling_method=None):
    # save all logs with fail() caller test name and timestamp
    fail_timestamp = lib.generate_now_timestamp()
    if not calling_method:
        # probably the fail() won't be deeper in stack than 10
        for depth in xrange(10):
            try:
                calling_method = str(sys._getframe(depth).f_code.co_name)
            except ValueError:
                print 'Error: test method not found in calling stack. ' \
                      'Fix your testing code or this fail() override.'
                super(SomeTest, self).fail(msg)
            if 'test' in calling_method:
                break

    print 'DEBUG: calling method: ' + calling_method
    logs_location = self.save_all_logs(calling_method, fail_timestamp)

    super(SomeTest, self).fail(msg + '\nLogs are located in: ' + logs_location)
```